# Can't pass PDO Connection instance into another class instance

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello I have a sample project I'm working on and I have created so far 5 php files.

```
connection_info.php -> db credentials
connection.php -> database connection
database.php -> where all wueries will be (here I pass the connection instance)
logger.php -> a simple logger
index.php -> oh well index...
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php

    require_once 'logger.php';
    require_once 'connection.php';
    require_once 'database.php';

    $logger = new Logger();
    $connection = new Connection($connection_info['host'], $connection_info['db'], $connection_info['user'], $connection_info['pass'], $logger);
    $db = new Database($connection, $logger);




?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Administration</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php

        $db->authenticateUser("alex", "123456");

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Connection.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'connection_info.php';

Class Connection {

    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $host;
    private $db;
    private $con;
    private $logger;

    function __construct($host = '127.0.0.1', $db, $user, $pass = null, &$logger) {

        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->logger = $logger;

        try {

            $connectionString = "mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->db;charset=utf8";

            $this->con = new PDO($connectionString, $this->user, $this->pass);
            $this->logger->log('Database connection established');

            return $this->con;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            $this->logger->log('Database connection failed: ' .  $e->getMessage());

        }

    }

    function __destruct() {

        $this->con = null;

    }

}

?>
```

**Database.php**

```
<?php

    Class Database {

        private $connection;
        private $logger;

        function __construct(&$connection, &$logger) {

            $this->connection = $connection;
            $this->logger = $logger;

        }

        function __destruct() {

        }


        public function authenticateUser($user, $pass) {

            if (func_num_args() != 2) {

                $this->logger('Invalid arguemnts supplied while authenticating');

                return false;

            } else {

                try {

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user=:user AND pass=:pass";

                    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query); // Error occurs here
                    $stmt->bindValue(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':pass', md5($pass), PDO::PARAM_STR);

                    $stmt->execute();

                    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    if (count($results) == 1) {

                        $_SESSION['user'] = true;

                        return true;

                    } else {

                        $this->logger('Invalid credentials provided: "' . $user . '", "' . $pass . '"' );

                        return false;

                    }

                } catch (PDOException $e) {

                    $this->logger('Error retrieving user: "' . $user . '", ' . $e->getMessage() );

                    return false;

                }

            }

        }

    }

?>
```

And the error I'm getting is this: "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Connection::prepare() in D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\lab\feticcio\database.php on line 34"

I'm trying to figure this out myself but my mind got stuck probably it's something silly but I could use a second pair of eyes...

Comment: You class `Connection` indeed does not have a method called `prepare`! Just because `Connection::$con` is an object which has a method `prepare` doesn't mean that's automatically exposed on your `Connection` instance as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Connection" class has no method called "prepare". You're passing an instance of `Connection` into `Database`, and then calling a method called `prepare()` which doesn't exist in that class. Did you mean to call the `prepare()` method of the PD connection object (which is `$con` within your own Connection class)? You should expose that via a wrapper property (or method to directly expose the `$con->prepare()` method).

Comment: ...or just directly pass the `PDO` instance instead of a wrapper which doesn't really do anything...

Comment: @deceze that's also a good suggestion. I had assumed that maybe the OP wanted to do more with that class once this issue was sorted, but if not then I agree it's a bit of a pointless abstraction.

Comment: Actually there is a use why this class is separate, what I was forgetting is that if you want to return something else from a constructor you have to  call the constructor explicitly, which is not best practice.

Comment: @Syd You can't return anything from a constructor. It looks to me like you just want a *factory function*, not a whole class.

Comment: I've read and correct my if i'm wrong if you run $instance->__construct(); then it might actually return the instance of the PDO connection.

Comment: @Syd Yes, but 1) you're creating a second connection then, which is completely unnecessary, and 2) you should never run a constructor by hand; it is only meant to initialize the class instance upon *construction* and all code typically operates under the assumption that this is the one and only time the constructor is executed.

Comment: @deceze you are correct never thought about second connection